# how to call knockout custom binding update function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js. I have created a custom binding and applied it on anchor tag like this :

```
<a data-bind="custom : { param1 : 'text', param2: 'text' }">delete</a>

ko.bindingHandlers.custom = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      alert("init");
   },
   update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      alert("update");
   }
}
```

When i first load the page both the `init` and `update` functions called. But when i click on delete link `update` function is not call. I want to call update function of my custom binding whenever i click over the delete link. What i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5):

The update function is only called initially when knockout applies the bindings and if any referenced observables are changed.

Your update function doesn't reference any observables and therefore doesn't get called again beyond the initial call.

If you want your function to be called when you click on it, you should use the [`click`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i did`nt get it how to use click binding to call update function, can u please give a short example

Comment: Well it would depend on what you want to be able to do with those parameters.  There's not a lot to work with in your example.  Did you need those values in the action?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a function on click of 'delete', then apply binding again in that function. Your problem will be solved. Because you have bind value when 1st time it loads, not on delete click.

```
<a data-bind="custom : { param1 : 'text', param2: 'text' }" 
   onclick='delete()'>delete</a>

<script type=javascript>
    function delete(){ ko.applyBindings(ko.bindingHandlers.custom);}
</script>
```